# Inherit res.company model in new custom module

Tags: odoo-14

I have create new module and create model as;

class CustomResCompany(models.Model):
_inherit = "res.company"

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    new_company = super(CustomResCompany, self).create(vals)
    self.env['stock.picking.type'].sudo().create({
        'name': 'Return',
        'sequence_code': 'IN',
        'code': 'outgoing',
        'company_id': new_company.id,
    })
    return new_company
```

I install the module but when run, pointer not comes in this code. Means this code not work and no error comes.

But when i paste this code an other module model file, it works perfectly.

Please guide where i am missing some thing.

Comment: I have noticed that i have forgotten to create  __init__.py  file.
Now the code is working condition and i can debug.

Comment: I have to pass warehouse_id as well but could not know how to get value of warehouse_id.